# Toogle P on A click ... Only one at the time

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

(EXAMPLE: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/EtpmK)

```
<a href="#">OPEN 1</a>
<p>TEXT 1</p>
<a href="#">OPEN 2</a>
<p>TEXT 2</p>
```

And I have the following JS:

```
$('a').click(function (event) {  
  $('p').removeClass('open');
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
  return false;
});
$('html').click(function (event) {
  $('p').removeClass('open');
});
```

So when I click a link the next paragraph opens or closes.

But I want to have only one paragraph opened at a time ...
So I added

```
$('p').removeClass('open');
```

inside

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
```

But now I a paragraph does not close when I click the link. It only opens.

It seems the toggle stops working ... How can I solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is since you are removing `open` from all `p`s, when the `toggle` is executed it always adds the class. The solution is not to remove the class `open` from the clicked `a` element's next `p` element

```
var $ps = $('p');
$('a').click(function (event) {
    var $next = $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
    $ps.not($next).removeClass('open');
    return false;
});
$('html').click(function (event) {
    $ps.removeClass('open');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YfUwZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple change over here as removing `open` from all `p` results in adding always the class `open` to the `p` tag off whose anchor is clicked.

```
$('a').click(function (event) {  
  $(this).next().toggleClass('open');
  $('p').not($(this).next()).removeClass('open');
  return false;
});
$('html').click(function (event) {
  $('p').removeClass('open');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvzU6/1/